# asp.net datalist select all checkboxes per category

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, datalist

I have a page where users can select different documents files in a datalist control. The documents are categorized based on categories using the on pre-render event handler. Documents are selected based on Checkbox controls (not Checkboxlist). So far so good. What I want to happen next is to put a 'Select All' checkbox beside each Category's name which should select only checkboxes under that category. Here is the datalist control:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" OnPreRender="DataList1_PreRender" DataKeyField="docid" EnableViewState="false">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tbl_data">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl_cb_all" visible="false">Select All <input runat="server" id="cb_selectall" type="checkbox" value='<%# Eval("catid") %>' /> </asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr runat="server" id="tr_data">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_categoryname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("categoryname") %>' Visible="false" /> <!-- Hide this; only used in Code Behind -->
                 <input runat="server" id="cb_docid" type="checkbox" value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' />
                  <asp:Hyperlink ID="hpl_docfileencr" Text='<%# Eval("docfileencr") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDFEncr/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "docfileencr") %>' Target="_blank"  runat="server" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and here is the OnPreRender code:

```
protected void DataList1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strTempLabelCategory = "";
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {



        Label lbl_categoryname = item.FindControl("lbl_categoryname") as Label;


        if (strTempLabelCategory.ToUpper() != lbl_categoryname.Text.ToString().ToUpper())
        {
            strTempLabelCategory = lbl_categoryname.Text.ToString().ToUpper();
            Label lblHeader = item.FindControl("lblHeader") as Label;
            lblHeader.Text = strTempLabelCategory.ToUpper();

            Label lbltempdiv = item.FindControl("lbl_cb_all") as Label;
            lbltempdiv.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked for something which can work within my code but no luck. And I am too invested in this code to now try Checkboxlist control (not sure if that would help anyway).
Any ideas? I thought I could use: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=77 code but not sure how I can make that work? If I can somehow make the select all checkbox tie to a  tag and then look for all  tag then may be the link's code would help.
Thanks!

Comment: use jquery to check the boxes for the items that are children of the datalist element. when the select all is checked it fires the jquery to get the datalist element by id then cycle through the children that are inputs of checkbox type and toggles these on.

Comment: Brian, thanks. But my problem is to figure out the 'datalist element by id then cycle through the children'...

Comment: I tried to have each ItemTemplate contain a table with tbl_data ID and then find the parent tbl_data table to drill into the checkboxes inside the tr_data row to look for the checkboxes but the tables tbl_data is rendering for each item.

Comment: yeah you want to avoid that.   how are you creating the asp:datalist? that would be what you need to identify, or is everything in one datalist and just sorted by catagory.  if so the first thing is to break it out by catagory so each one is wrapped in some identifying element.

Comment: Brian, both the relevant .aspx and the .cs code is in my post. In order to group by categories I am using pre-render. Even the Select All checkbox (as can be seen in the .aspx) shows up as expected. I was hoping I could assign the tr element containing the checkboxes id similar to the selectall checkbox but .net is not allowing dynamic IDs. Thanks!

Comment: Still no solution. I will checkback later.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use HiddenFields to store `CatID` and `DocID`
2. Use ASP.NET CheckBoxes instead of HTML-Inputs for both
3. Handle the Check-All Checkbox' `CheckedChanged` event:

---

```
protected void CheckAllChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkAll = (CheckBox)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)checkAll.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField HiddenCatID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenCatID");
    var catCheckBoxes = DataList1.Items.Cast<DataListItem>()
        .Where(li => ((HiddenField)li.FindControl("HiddenCatID")).Value == HiddenCatID.Value)
        .Select(li => li.FindControl("cb_docid"));
    foreach (CheckBox docCheckBox in catCheckBoxes)
    {
        docCheckBox.Checked = checkAll.Checked;
    }
}
```

on aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  id="cb_selectall" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenCatID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDocID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DocID") %>' />
```

You also need to `EnableViewState=true` on the DataList to maintain checkbox state and enable checking/unchecking.

---

**Edit**:

Because you have problems to get it running, here's a complete working sample page.

Here are the required controls on aspx(note f.e. `<tr runat="server" id="tr_category">)`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tbl_data">
        <tr runat="server" id="tr_category">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("categoryname") %>' Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_cb_all">Select All
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  id="cb_selectall" />
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="tr_data">
            <td>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenCatID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="cb_docid" />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_docfileencr" Text='<%# Eval("docfileencr") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDFEncr/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "docfileencr") %>'
                    Target="_blank" runat="server" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

1. Ensure that the DataList is databound only `if(!IsPostback)`, otherwise the checkbox selection will not be maintained:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!IsPostBack) BindDataList();
   }
   ```
2. I'm using `ItemDataBound` instead of `PreRender` which is important for the ViewState to be reloaded correctly. I've also simplified all:

   ```
   protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
       {
           var row  = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
           var view = row.DataView;
           var lastRow = e.Item.ItemIndex == 0 ? null : view[e.Item.ItemIndex-1];
           var tr_category = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("tr_category");
           var sameCategory = lastRow != null && (int)row["catid"] == (int)lastRow["catid"];
           tr_category.Visible = !sameCategory;
       }
   }
   ```
3. The `CheckAllChanged` remains unchanged.

This works as expected even if you select a single document-checkbox and select a category-checkbox afterwards which causes a postback.

Comment: Tim: Your coding is working. I will post an update later. Still need to figure out the 'uncheck' to remove all checkboxes as well as having the database processing to use the asp:checkbox now instead of the html checkbox before. Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by 'uncheck'? Unchecking the doc-checkboxes for each category works already the same way you check them, simply by unchecking the category checkbox.

Comment: <asp:CheckBox runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  id="cb_selectall" /> If I uncheck the cb_selectall then it does not cause the corresponding category's checkboxes to become unchecked

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this is caused by your `EnableViewState=false` on the DataList.

Comment: Yes, you are right: I made ViewState to be true for Datalist and now the uncheck work. Final question, I think.  HtmlInputCheckBox cb = li.FindControl("cb_docid") as HtmlInputCheckBox; was my previous way to get the 'value' of docid from the html checkboxes. But I can't use it anymore since I changed to asp:checkboxes. I get an error about 'value' not a member. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use a `HiddenField`to store the `DocID` in the same way as you store the `CatID`. Then you get it via `var docID=HiddenField HiddenDocID = ((HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenDocID")).Value;` (edited my asnwer accordingly)

Comment: I am not sure I have yet to digest your solution fully, especially the 'selectAllChanged' handler  yet and so not sure how to implement this. I have added a hidden field like the following but don't know what to do next:  <asp:CheckBox runat="server"  id="cb_docid"  value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' />
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDocID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' />

Comment: I think I already incorporated the hiddenfield for docid. Need to go beyond it

Comment: Never mind. I think I got it! Per your suggestion, I have a HiddenField:  <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDocID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' /> and in the PreRender event, I have this:  HiddenField HiddenDocID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenDocID");
            CheckBox cb_documents = item.FindControl("cb_docid") as CheckBox;
            cb_documents.InputAttributes.Add("docid", HiddenDocID.Value.ToString()); then, during the final database stage, see my next comment:

Comment: HiddenField docid = li.FindControl("HiddenDocID") as HiddenField; string dbcmd = @"Insert Into [order_details] (orderid,docid) Values (" + orderid + "," + docid.Value.ToString() + ")";

Comment: Tim: There is still one problem: One an individual checkbox is checked under a Category and then I select a Select All checkbox for another Category then the individual Checkbox gets unchecked. That's obviously a problem. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9814/discussion-between-meengla-and-tim-schmelter)

Comment: @Meengla: I've created a complete working sample. Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Tim. Okay! I will try your updated answser... I hope it would address issues as I mentioned in our 'chat' here...

Comment: Tim: I may be making some progress with your new code although if I were to put-in !ispostback in pageload then the selectall trigger causes the datalist to not bind at all. So I removed it and now individual checkboxes stay selected after the selectall; so that's progress! Unchecking the selectall now does NOT remove the checks anymore. Hmmm. ***I will back tomorrow and give an update.*** I am on the Eastern Time Zone. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this to work with slight modification of Tim's code. A few points: I had to disable ViewState for the datalist because, otherwise, the check-all trigger was not keeping boxes checked. I don't understand why. Also, there is not ispostback check in the page_load event and the datalist binds on every load. I am not that's 'optimal' or not. I have also made two sets of Asp:RadioButtons: CheckAll and CheckNone, instead of checkboxes. Anyway, here is the relevant code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" DataKeyField="docid"
                EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tbl_data">
                        <tr runat="server" id="tr_category">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("categoryname") %>'
                                    Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_cb_all">Select: All
                                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        ID="rb_selectall" GroupName="selectallnone" />
                                    | None
                                    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckAllChangedNone" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        ID="rb_selectnone" GroupName="selectallnone" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenCatID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CatID") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDocID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' />
                                </asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server" id="tr_data">
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb_docid" Value='<%# Eval("docid") %>' />
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_docfileencr" Text='<%# Eval("docfileencr") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDFEncr/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "docfileencr") %>'
                                    Target="_blank" runat="server" />
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>

 protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        var view = row.DataView;
        var lastRow = e.Item.ItemIndex == 0 ? null : view[e.Item.ItemIndex - 1];
        var tr_category = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("tr_category");
        var sameCategory = lastRow != null && (int)row["catid"] == (int)lastRow["catid"];
        tr_category.Visible = !sameCategory;
    }
}

protected void CheckAllChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton checkAll = (RadioButton)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)checkAll.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField HiddenCatID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenCatID");

    var catCheckBoxes = DataList1.Items.Cast<DataListItem>()
        .Where(li => ((HiddenField)li.FindControl("HiddenCatID")).Value == HiddenCatID.Value)
        .Select(li => li.FindControl("cb_docid"))
        .ToList();
    foreach (CheckBox docCheckBox in catCheckBoxes)
    {
       // docCheckBox.Checked = checkAll.Checked;
        docCheckBox.Checked = true;
    }
 }

protected void CheckAllChangedNone(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton checkAll = (RadioButton)sender;
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)checkAll.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField HiddenCatID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenCatID");

    var catCheckBoxes = DataList1.Items.Cast<DataListItem>()
        .Where(li => ((HiddenField)li.FindControl("HiddenCatID")).Value == HiddenCatID.Value)
        .Select(li => li.FindControl("cb_docid"))
        .ToList();

    foreach (CheckBox docCheckBox in catCheckBoxes)
    {
        docCheckBox.Checked = false;
    }


}
```

//partial code from the Order button follows; note the use of HiddenField

```
 CheckBox cb = li.FindControl("cb_docid") as CheckBox;

        if (cb != null)
        {
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                HiddenField docid = li.FindControl("HiddenDocID") as HiddenField;
                string dbcmd = @"Insert Into [order_details] (orderid,docid) Values (" + orderid + "," + docid.Value.ToString() + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void chkAllN_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSelectedRecord.InnerText = "0";
        /*this Foreach Loop performing for find gridview*/
        foreach (DataListItem dst in dstMulEmpSalInsert.Items)
        {
            GridView grd = (GridView)dst.FindControl("grdMulEmpSalInsert");
            CheckBox chk_All = (CheckBox)grd.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkAllN");

            if (chk_All.Checked == true)
            {
                /*this Foreach Loop performing for find gridview Controls*/
                foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grd.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox chk_One = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("ChkSendOne");
                    

                    chk_One.Checked = true;
                    txt_Salary.ReadOnly = false;
                    lblSelectedRecord.InnerText = (Convert.ToInt32(lblSelectedRecord.InnerText) + 1).ToString();
                }
               

            }
            else
            {
                /*this Foreach Loop performing for find gridview Controls*/
                foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grd.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox chk_One = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("ChkSendOne");
                    

                    chk_One.Checked = false;
                    

                }
                
            }
        }
        

    }
```